# tag manager v2 getting event data fields

Tags: configuration, google-analytics, tags, seo

I'm developing a cordova/phonegap app and I'm tracking events with a function like this: 
`tagManager.trackEvent(success, error, category, eventAction, eventLabel, eventValue);`

I want to track every event that I send from my webapp and send it to google analytics.

What I haven't been able to find out it's how to fill the following fields on GTM, so it sends all the event fields to GA.

[image: TAG configuration]

Fields: `category`,`eventAction`,`eventLabel`,`eventValue`

At first I wasn't getting hits at all on GA (because I hadn't fill any of those fields on the GA tag configuration). Then, I found out that at least one of those fields didn't have to empty, so I filled one and I started getting hits on GA, but only the info I placed on those fields (e.g I put "App events" on the category field but all the data that was getting on GA was the category event "App events").

I can't create a variable with the type "dataLayer" since there isn't that type on the "create variable options" (on GTM)

[image: Options]

These are the only options I have when creating a variable.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not about programing

Comment: I don't speak spanish, but per Google Translate 'Variable de capa de datos" means "Variable data layer" which sounds promising.